# What browsers support "!important"?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Which browsers support the CSS !important directive, and what are the various quirks amongst the different browsers that do support it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Excellent browser support.**

It was part of the [CSS1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#important) and has been around forever, and was always easy enough to implement that browsers appear to have gotten it right on the first try.

At the very least (from personal experience) IE5.5+, Firefox 1+, Safari 3+, Chrome 1+.

Pretty much supported by every browser that supports CSS (which is every browser you care about).

Comment: IE6 officially supports it, but it doesn't actually work in IE6 the way it should

Comment: @Darko do you have an example of IE6 not supporting !important correctly?

Comment: Yeah try the example from my answer and you'll see. just substitute width for background so its easier to see. you can also try jimyi's answer to see the same

Comment: I see that now, and see how it's useful as a hack. However, reading the CSS1 spec I can't call it a "bug".

Comment: This is easily the best news I've heard all year. Always been a suspicion that it was cross-universe, now it is fact in my mind.

Comment: *cough* <strike>####</strike>burn IE6 *cough*

Answer (score 7):

[According to Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29), IE7, FireFox 1.0, Safari 1.0, Opera 7, and Chrome *fully* support !important.  IE6 supports it, but it does have a bug.  If you do this, color will be red:

```
h1 {
  color: green !important;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any browser which supports CSS1+ - ie, any browser that supports CSS - even IE. Even if the CSS implementations are not fully standards-compliant, `!important` is a core CSS feature.

To elaborate, IIRC, IE5+, all Firefox, most Netscape, Opera, Safari, Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

All browsers apart from IE6 support it which makes it quite handy for CSS hacks. Example:

```
#someElement { width:200px !important; width:198px; }
```

All browsers apart from IE6 will render `#someElement` at 200px because they will honor the `!important`. IE6 however will just ignore the `!important` and render `#someElement` at 198px.

**EDIT:** Most common use case scenario for this (at least with me) is using it to correct the double margin bug in IE6