# Cannot find gridview row with jQuery skin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

My jQuery script does not work when I have a skin applied to my gridview. Once I add in the skin I cannot find the tr anymore. I assume it has something to do with the way the tr gets constructed. Without the skin, the row is a clean

```
    <tr>data</tr>.
```

But with the skin the row is now

```
<tr style=....>data</tr>
```

Here is my jQuery that does work when I do not have skin applied to the gv.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('highlightrow');
                }).mouseout(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('highlightrow');
                })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows are found just fine, problem is that they have "hard coded" background color in their `style` so the background color in the `class` has no effect.

One way around this is to store the previous color then directly set the background color in `mouseover` and restore the previous color (to preserve the skin) in the mouse out event.

Code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).data("prev_color", $(this).css("background-color"));
        $(this).toggleClass('highlightrow').css("background-color", "yellow");
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlightrow').css("background-color", $(this).data("prev_color"));
    });
});
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/awEaP/1/

Comment: thanks! Works great. I just added  $('tr:not(:first)').mouseover(function () { to avoid highlighting the header.

Comment: @IMAbev cheers, glad I could help and thanks for sharing this useful information! :)

Comment: fyi I had multiple gridviews on a page all with .gridlink class. tr:not(:first) only effects the first gridview. I changed to tr:not(:firstchild) and it highlighted only the rows on all gv's - not the headers

Answer (score 1):

I bet it is due to `style` having higher priority than your `css`. How is your `highlightrow` defined? For example if you specify a `background-color` here and it is also in the `tr`'s `style`, it gets ignored.

Maybe adding the `!important` clause could help:

```
.highlightrow
{
    background-color: Red !important;
}
```

Comment: that does work. The only down side (minor) is that it highlights the table head too.  Never knew of the !important clause. I wonder about it's browser support?

Comment: @IMA here is explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189621/when-does-csss-important-declaration-not-work

Comment: @IMAbev: about !important support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330184/what-browsers-support-important