# How can I override anchor tag properties?

Tags: html, css

I already have this code in my style.css (using wordpress):

```
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #3088FF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I want to change the anchor text color, font style, bold etc for categories. How can I override this?

Comment: You mean the anchor got inline style (e.g. `<a style="color: red;" ...>`) which you want to override with CSS?

Comment: HI, this anchor CSS just need to change to some specific widget, thats all, BUT it shouldnt change over all CSS...

Answer (score 5):

If you must overwrite existing styles, use the `!important` declaration.  For example,

```
.myStyledLink{
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Comment: HI, BUT I just wanna apply this anchor text CSS only to that particular anchors, my override CSS shouldnt change actual behavior of CSS.. So, does this !important; can only be used for specific anchor tags..?

Comment: You can use a class on the anchors which you want to override the css rules. `<a href="" class="myStyledLink">MyLinkText</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the anchor has inline style already that you wish to override with CSS, use the `!important` keyword:

```
<a href="#" style="color: red;">hello</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #3088FF !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/3873c/).

This will override all other styles including inline style and if you are worried about cross browser compatibility then you shouldn't: [What browsers support "!important"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330184/what-browsers-support-important)

Comment: HI, BUT I just wanna apply this anchor text CSS only to that particular anchors, my override CSS shouldnt change actual behavior of CSS.. So, does this !important; can only be used for specific anchor tags..?

Comment: @Lisa for this you will have to add `class="something"` to the anchors you want and have `.something { color: #3088FF !important; }`

Answer (score 2):

Identify the ID of the categories widget in your output HTML. Let's say that `id="widget-cat"`, then create a CSS rule as follows to override the link colours within that widget, e.g.

```
#widget-cat a:link, #widget-cat a:visited  {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

The use of `!important` is a very last resort to overriding styles really, and I recommend only ever using that if you need to override CSS rules that can't be made more specific and were written by third-party developers that you have no control over.